# Use multiple parameters for route middleware in Laravel 6.0

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

In my Laravel 6.0 app, I need to use a route with two parameters.

```php
Route::get('view/{MyFirstModel}/{MySecondModel}', 'Mycontroller@view')
    ->middleware(['can:view,MyFirstModel,MySecondModel']);
```

I tried also with:

```php
Route::get('view/{MyFirstModel}/{MySecondModel}', 'Mycontroller@view')
    ->middleware(['can:view,MyFirstModel|MySecondModel']);
```

In my Policy I have:

```php
public function view(User $user, MyFirstModel $first, MySecondModel $second) {
    var_dump("I enter");
}
```

However, it doesn't work, and the policy is never called. How can I  pass two parameters in my route middleware?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my error.

Seems that I should use this sintax:

```
Route::get('view/{MyFirstModel}/{MySecondModel}', 'Mycontroller@view')->middleware('can:view,MyFirstModel,MySecondModel')
```

Without parentheses.